# Параметр m в Вихре Мерсенна (std::mt19937) C++

Tags: c++, std

возник вопрос касательно параметров Вихря Мерсенна в библиотеке std. Согласно документации, параметр m (Число Мерсенна) равен 397. Однако, данное число хоть и является простым, но не является числом Мерсенна. Как это можно обосновать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это объясняется тем, что параметр `m` не обязан быть числом Мерсенна. С чего вы взяли, что `m` должен равняться числу Мерсенна?

Comment: Вас понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. почитать определение чисел Мерсенна в Википедии. Конкретно это: число Мерсенна = число вида 2^n - 1; более строго - это такое число вида 2^n - 1, где n - само по себе простое число.
2. проверить ваше число на соответствие этой формуле.

Comment: Так в том то и проблема, что данное число не является числом Мерсенна, но оно используется в движке MT19973 по-умолчанию, в библиотеке STD.

Comment: Хотелось бы понять, как это допускается

Comment: Вы спросили как это обосновать. Я вам дал формулировку, можете предъявлять претензии.

Может быть, это ваше число является не собственно числом Мерсенна, а его показателем? Т.е., само число равно 2^397 - 1. Тогда все правильно.

Comment: Уже разобрался, спсаибо, неправильно понял документацию по методу